# Exporting video from compositing

Tags: export, compositing-nodes, video

So I've only just started blender, and the first thing I did was use compositing to change a greenscreen to something else. I followed a tutorial, but when it got to saving the file, it got more vague. I set it to an FFmpeg video file where it says "file for..." and MPEG-4 as the container, which is what the video said to do, but I don't know what to do now. I rendered it, but from there it only let me save as still images. What do I do?

Comment: Hello, do you prefer to render a video or a series of images? Generally it is recommended to first render a series of images (PNG is better quality than JPG) then import the images in another blend file and render as video

Answer (score 1):

When you run a "Render Animation" (I.E. by pressing <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> or using the menu *Render* > *Render Animation*), Blender will write files as per your scene's output settings.

If you set a FFmpeg-encoded video, unless you had invalid encoding parameters (which should have canceled your render), you should see the video file in the folder you asked to be saved.

If you are unsure where that is, you can always hit the folder icon next to the file output path, which will open the folder in Blender's File Browser:

[image]

### When using Compositing nodes

Make sure you output your node tree to the *Composite* node, this node is what is sent to the scene's file saving process:

[image]

Alternatively, if you want more complex file output (I.E. saving different versions of your compositing in different files, saving passes and whatnot), you can also use a <kbd>File</kbd><kbd>Output</kbd> node. Although, it can only save image files, and Blender will still use the scene's render settings to output a file in addition to what you set up in the File Output node.

[image]